# Bootstrap basic alignment issue

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, program-entry-point, navbar

So I am having an issue aligning my navbar with my form in the main-content area. I know it's a simple fix,but I've checked my code and looked for a solution with no luck.

Anyways, check it out: http://bootply.com/67191

Answer (score 1):

Put a `<div class="row"></div>` around your `span12`...

**[DEMO](http://bootply.com/67193)**

Comment: No problem... All of your `.span` classes will be wrapped with a `.row` class. Refer to [these docs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).